# Display BLOB Field (Containing Text) in RDLC Report Dynamics NAV

Tags: blob, rdlc, dynamics-nav

I have the field Note from table Record Link that i want to display in an rdlc report. How can i include it in the dataset to loop into the BLOB field to extract the text value ? Using NAV90

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Notes are stored as Binary Text.
You need to use .NET to read out the value into a string.

From the .NET side of things you'll need:

- **BinaryReader** from *'mscorlib, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089'.System.IO.BinaryReader*
- **Encoding** from *'mscorlib, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089'.System.Text.Encoding*

As for reading the actual BLOB into a string:

```
RecordLink.Note.CREATEINSTREAM(InStream);
BinaryReader := BinaryReader.BinaryReader(InStream,Encoding.UTF8,FALSE);
MESSAGE('Your note text is %1',BinaryReader.ReadString);
```

Comment: Thanks Working, but how can i pass the value to rdlc layout. If i create a variable and store it inside, the max will be 1024 of length

Comment: Declare your Text without a length. Note that you can't actually store a heap of data in Notes -- it has a (varying) limit around 700 characters from memory. Probably a binary size restriction.

Comment: I didnt place it as a variable instead i just called the function BinaryReader.ReadString directly from the dataitem line, and it do works. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

The text can be retrieved without the use of DotNet variables.

```
CommentStream : InStream;
CommentText : Text;
```

good:

```
tbl.CALCFIELDS(Comments);
tbl.Comments.CREATEINSTREAM(CommentStream);
CommentStream.READTEXT(CommentText);
```

In my case including the text encoding parameter like this wasn't working.  It was for a while, but stopped working.  The reason for the inconsistency eludes me, but nonetheless removing the text encoding argument fixed it.

bad:

```
tbl.CALCFIELDS(Comments);
tbl.Comments.CREATEINSTREAM(CommentStream, TEXTENCODING::UTF8);
CommentStream.READTEXT(CommentText);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
BigTextVar.ADDTEXT('Text which has length greater than 1024...');

StringHelper: System.String.'mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089' (DotNet Var)

DataItem.Column.SourceExpression = StringHelper.Copy(FORMAT(BigTextVar))
```

This is the trick to pass BigText into Report RDLC layout without using more Column

I tried in Dynamics NAV 2017 and it works well!